# @font-face is not working in WordPress

Tags: customization, themes

I have a font I want to use with my links. Somehow it doesn't work.

```
@font-face {
      font-family: HelveticaNeueLight;
      src: local('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf');
   }
```

My font path is: `wp-content/themes/mytheme/fonts/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf`, and I used it like this:

```
.jplnav li a {
     font-family: HelveticaNeueLight;
   }
```

Browser: Chrome

Is there some kind of special code need to make @font-face work?

Comment: You need not to specify the `local()`. Just use it like: `src: URL('fonts/HelveticaNeueLight.ttf');` If I'm not wrong, it will work for you. As per as I know specifying `local()` will lead the browser to your local hard drive.. in most of the cases it's used to specify the file into the `C:\\Windows\Fonts`. But for web a better option is using @font-face with webfont generator.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your browser and platform you need to specify the font in different formats.
See this example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "LeagueGothic";
  src: url('../fonts/league_gothic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/league_gothic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
       url('../fonts/league_gothic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/league_gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/league_gothic-webfont.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/league_gothic-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: "normal";
  font-style: "normal";
}
```

If you just have the font in `.ttf` format and need the others, you can use the [FontSquirrel's WebFont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create your own @font-face kit.

Comment: Thanks, im using chrome, ttf should work with chrome right??

Comment: In my experience, generating webfont kit with `.otf` file, doesn't work with ease. But `.ttf` won't create problem for you. Mark pointed you to the right direction - just follow it. :)

Comment: Chrome on Ubuntu just specifying the ttf works. Are you sure your path is correct? If you are using chrome open the developer tools and reload the page it should say if it loads the file. Secondly have you checked the rule is actually being applied, have you tried apply the font-face to the `body`?

Comment: Im not sure if my file path is correct. could you check the question, my path is there... anyway, ill check via inspect element.

Comment: Path is probably correct if you `style.css` is in the root of `wp-content/themes/mytheme/`